# OpenConnect "Unknown form id frmTotpToken" Error on Login

Tags: vpn, openconnect

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. I'm trying to login to VPN using Juniper / Pulse Network connect.
 After setting up the connection in the network manager, when I tried to login I got  `Unknown form id frmTotpToken`  error.

How do I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this has been addressed in a fork of openconnect.  See [this commit](https://github.com/cernekee/openconnect/commit/1ff34cb9689fbaf57decac537df1e32e799bb9c7) for details.